# I am unable to get remaining tableview cells in pagination with API calling in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, tableview

I need pagination for tableview so i have used [CCBottomRefreshControl](https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl) framework in my project

**code**: i have 100 of tableview cells... but **with this code I am getting only first 10 tableview cells**.. when i scroll down also i am not getting remaining cells.. why? how do i use pagination and get all remaining cells while scrolling

please do guide

```
import CCBottomRefreshControl

class ResultViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var resultTableView: UITableView!

var currentPageNumberVM: Int = 0
var isLoading = false

public var jobsData : Array<DataUser>?

var searchData = JobSearchResult_Base(dictionary: NSDictionary()) 

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

ResultServiceCall()
let bottomRefreshController = UIRefreshControl()
bottomRefreshController.triggerVerticalOffset = 50
bottomRefreshController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
self.resultTableView.bottomRefreshControl = bottomRefreshController
self.resultTableView.bottomRefreshControl?.tintColor = .clear

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.currentPageNumberVM = 0

}

@objc func refresh() {
ResultServiceCall}

func ResultServiceCall() {

let param = [
    "keyword": keyword,
    "job_type": job_type.map{String($0)}.joined(separator: ","),
    "page" : currentPageNumberVM
] as [String : Any]

APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param, method: .post, vc: self, url: CommonUrl.job_search_result, isTokenNeeded: true){ [weak self] (resp) in

    if (self?.currentPageNumberVM)! > 0 {
            if (JobSearchResult_Base(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())?.result?.jobs?.data ?? [DataUser]()).count > 0 {
                self?.searchData?.result?.jobs?.data! += JobSearchResult_Base(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())?.result?.jobs?.data ?? [DataUser]()
            }else {
            }
        }
        else{
            self?.searchData = JobSearchResult_Base(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
        }
        self?.resultTableView.bottomRefreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    self?.isLoading = false
    self?.jobsData = self?.searchData?.result?.jobs?.data
        self?.resultTableView.reloadData()
    self?.currentPageNumberVM += 1
}
}
```

where am i wrong, how do I use Pagination and get remaining cells.